# Explanation of results from retrieve triggered send summary SOAP API request

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

I have setup a SOAP API call to retrieve a summary of a triggered send definition, but I can't seem to explain why the results of the API request are split into numerous result blocks.

Here is an example of the response body (note that there are two "Results" nodes):

```
  <RetrieveResponseMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
     <RequestID>6f636b00-02e5-4fc0-b60e-fd15a428ca0d</RequestID>
     <Results xsi:type="TriggeredSendSummary">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Sent>235</Sent>
        <NotSentDueToError>0</NotSentDueToError>
     </Results>
     <Results xsi:type="TriggeredSendSummary">
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Sent>1378</Sent>
        <NotSentDueToError>82</NotSentDueToError>
     </Results>
  </RetrieveResponseMsg>
```

I have compared these results to the tracking reports in the ET UI, but can't seem to correlate the two result blocks with any sort of time period (day/week/month), nor is there any information in the [documentation](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/soap-api/retrieving-a-triggered-send-summary.html) explaining how to interpret the response.

Can anyone shed some light on why the response is chunked in this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a stab in the dark, but perhaps your Triggered Send Definition was sent to 2 times.  That is a summary of each execution of it.  You could try adding more properties to the response ([Triggered Send Summary](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/triggeredsendsummary/)), like CorrelationID and CreatedDate.  If those are the same, ExactTarget may have broken up your send into 2 workloads.  Not 100% sure they do such a thing, but a matching CorrelationID would infer it.